# Spark randomize values of a primary key column in another unique column ensuring no collisions

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, random, shuffle

So I have this problem which is bugging me for a while ...
I need to generate all possible values of ssn format xx-xxx-xxxx where x is any number from 0 to 9 in 1 column of a spark dataframe and then add a column which basically should contain the same values, but different than the initial column on each row.

Practical example with a small set of 0/1 possible values:

```
+-----------+-----------+
|ssn        |false_ssn  |
+-----------+-----------+
|00-000-0000|01-001-0000|
|00-000-0001|00-001-0001|
|00-001-0000|00-000-0001|
|00-001-0001|01-000-0000|
|01-000-0000|01-001-0001|
|01-000-0001|00-000-0000|
|01-001-0000|00-001-0000|
|01-001-0001|01-000-0001|
+-----------+-----------+
```

I managed to do this using this python code:

```
def generate_ssn_lookup_data(range_group_1: int, range_group_2: int, range_group_3: int,
                             spark: SparkSession) -> DataFrame:
    # Generate data
    sensitive_values = [f"{i:02d}-{j:03d}-{k:04d}"
                        for i in range(range_group_1)
                        for j in range(range_group_2)
                        for k in range(range_group_3)]
    mock_values = []
    used_values = set()
    for sensitive in sensitive_values:
        mock = sensitive
        while mock == sensitive or mock in used_values:
            mock = f"{random.choice(range(range_group_1)):02d}-{random.choice(range(range_group_2)):03d}-{random.choice(range(range_group_3)):04d}"
        mock_values.append(mock)
        used_values.add(mock)
    data = [(sensitive, mock) for sensitive, mock in zip(sensitive_values, mock_values)]

    df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["ssn", "false_ssn"])
    return df

#Call 
df = generate_ssn_lookup_data(2, 2, 2, some_spark_session)
```

But you can imagine how this performs when trying to generate 1billion records with `generate_ssn_lookup_data(100, 1000, 10000, some_spark_session)`

So I also tried using spark native functions with the code below, but I can't avoid collisions where false_ssn = ssn (I added the hole debug code here, for actual values use a call like: `generate_ssn_lookup_data(0, 9)`)  ... I'm guessing the fact that I try to ensure unique randoms is not enough, as actually the row_numbers could match for the same values... that loop though is worrying.

```
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr, rand, col, lit, concat, floor, when, row_number

spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]") \
    .config("spark.driver.memory", "8g") \
    .config("spark.executor.memory", "8g") \
    .appName("App").getOrCreate()


def generate_ssn_lookup_data(start: int, end: int) -> DataFrame:
    df = spark.range(1).select(expr("null").alias("dummy"))
    ssn_characters = 9
    for _ in range(ssn_characters):
        df = df.crossJoin(spark.range(start, end + 1).select(col("id").alias("col" + str(_))))

    df = df.withColumn("ssn", concat(
        col("col0"), col("col1"), lit("-"),
        col("col2"), col("col3"), col("col4"), lit("-"),
        col("col5"), col("col6"), col("col7"), col("col8")
    )) \
        .withColumn("random", floor(rand() * pow(10, 15))) \
        .withColumn("random2", floor(rand() * pow(10, 15)))

    df = ensure_unique_random(df, random_col1="random", random_col2="random2")
    left = df.withColumn("rnd", row_number().over(Window.orderBy("random")))
    right = df.withColumnRenamed("ssn", "false_ssn").withColumn("rnd", row_number().over(Window.orderBy("random2")))
    df = left.alias("l").join(right.alias("r"), left.rnd == right.rnd).drop("rnd")

    return df.select("l.ssn", "r.false_ssn")


def ensure_unique_random(df: DataFrame, random_col1, random_col2) -> DataFrame:
    while df.where(f"{random_col1} = {random_col2}").count() != 0:
        df.where(f"{random_col1} = {random_col2}").show(truncate=False)
        df = df.withColumn(random_col2,
                           when(col(random_col1) == col(random_col2), 100).otherwise(
                               col(random_col2)))
    return df


df = generate_ssn_lookup_data(0, 1)
df.cache()
print("Generated Df ")
df.show(truncate=False)
df_count = df.count()
print(f"Generated Df Count: {df_count}")
unique_ssn_count = df.select("ssn").distinct().count()
print(f"Distinct SSN Count: {unique_ssn_count}")
false_ssn_count = df.select("false_ssn").distinct().count()
print(f"Distinct False Count: {false_ssn_count} ")
false_non_false_collisions = df.where("ssn = false_ssn")
collision_count = false_non_false_collisions.count()
print(f"False Non False Collisions: {false_non_false_collisions.count()}")
false_non_false_collisions.show(truncate=False)
assert (collision_count == 0)
```

Basically the problem is shuffling the values of columnA into column ensuring no duplicates appear on columnB and no columnB will equal columnA.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [sort](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.sort.html) the dataframe by a [random](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.4.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.rand.html) value. This sort operation moves each row into a random partition. In a second step, each row gets the `ssn` of the previous row within the same partition assigned as `false_ssn` using [mapPartitions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.4.0/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.RDD.mapPartitions.html).

As the partitions consist of randomly chosen rows this approach assigns random values as `false_ssn`s. And as the second step is a deterministic operation no collisions can occur.

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

sensitive_values = ...

df = spark.createDataFrame(sensitive_values, schema=["ssn"])
df2 = df.sort(F.rand()) \
    .repartition(2) #needs to be adjusted, see below

def reorder(rows):
    first_element = next(rows)
    prev_element = first_element
    for row in rows:
        l=prev_element
        prev_element=row
        yield l + (row.ssn,)
    yield prev_element + (first_element.ssn,)

df2.rdd.mapPartitions(reorder).toDF(df2.columns + ["false_ssn"]) \
    .show()
```

Output:

```
+-----------+-----------+
|        ssn|  false_ssn|
+-----------+-----------+
|00-001-0000|01-000-0001|
|01-000-0001|00-001-0001|
|00-001-0001|01-001-0001|
|01-001-0001|01-000-0000|
|01-000-0000|00-001-0000|
|00-000-0001|01-001-0000|
|01-001-0000|00-000-0000|
|00-000-0000|00-000-0001|
+-----------+-----------+
```

*Remark*: the `repartition(2)` is required for (small) test datasets to ensure that there are no partitions with only one row. This value should be adjusted depending on the number of rows so that there are no partitions with only one row.

Comment: Nice, thanks... so simple I wasn't aware of the ability to take previous or next row values without lag or lead. I actually found another way yesterday, but it would be much more resource intensive. (zipwithindex-shuffle-join-check for colisions in a loop and fix them 1 by 1). I'll try this one out and accept this answer if it works well.Question: What happens with the last row in the last partition?

Comment: The last row of each partition is mapped to the first row of the same partition. This is the reason for the variable `first_element`.